# Authorising child objects through a parent's association using CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization, cancan

Can we check permissions on a child object based on an association of the parent?

I have a many-to-many association (see associations below) between `Group` (the parent) and `User`, through `Membership` (the association). I have an `Event` (the child) model that belongs to a `Group` and a `User`. `Membership` has a column called `role`, and this is what I want to base my permissions on.

I want to ensure that a `user` can only create a `event` if the `user` is the `owner` of the `group` that the `event` belongs to. By `owner` I mean there is `Membership.where(user_id: user, group_id: group, role: 'admin')` record.

The docs allude to this under [Accessing Parent in Ability](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Nested-Resources), but they mention nothing about going through an association.

```
# in Ability
can :manage, Task, :project => { :user_id => user.id }
```

To translate that example to my use case:

```
# in Ability
can :create, Event, :group => { group.owner == user }
```

I already have a group.owner setup:

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group, inverse_of: :memberships
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships

  has_many :ownerships, class_name: 'Membership', conditions: { role: 'admin' }
  has_many :owned_groups, through: :ownerships, source: :group

  has_many :events
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships

  has_one :ownership, class_name: 'Membership', conditions: { role: 'admin' }
  has_one :owner, through: :ownership, source: :user

  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organizer, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: What do your controllers look like?

Comment: I wish I could tell you, but we ditched CanCan for this project since it went up to Rails 4.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your permission should be based on the Group:

```
can :create_events, Group, owner_id: user.id
```

Are you using nested routes for groups & events?

**Edit:**

```
can :create_events, Group, owner: { id: user.id }
```

Comment: Zack, I'm not nesting. And this does not solve my issue: `Group` does not have `user_id`. `Membership`, the joiner model, has that.

Comment: Zack, that does not work, but this does: `can :create, Event, group: { :owner => user }` Feel free to edit your answer and include it, and I'll accept.